# Count Number of Trades with Less than Percentage Profit Target?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I am trying to calculate the **percentage of trades below profit target**, lets say 0.2%.
`strategy.eventrades` only provide the trades which are exactly breakeven i.e Profit% = Commission% which is not what i want.
I want to count the number of trades below a certain profit% and then divide them by `strategy.closedtrades` to get percentage of trades below profit target.

Answer (score 0):

I did a script with similar (but not exactly) calculations here
https://www.tradingview.com/script/Puprh5UJ-Strategy-Multiple-Orders-Statistics-Template-Educational/
Should give you a good starting point

Comment: Thanks alot. I already have the other things figured out, but am not able to find the count function